# ng build --prod for firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

Hello Im new to Angular and i am trying to host my angular project on firebase, So when i type in `ng build --prod`, it creates a folder (in this case 'store') containing the index.html and other files inside the dist folder:
[image]

But only the contents inside the dist folder are getting deployed and not the contents inside the store folder. So every time i have to copy the contents in the 'store' folder and paste it outside to the dist folder. Could you please help?

Comment: can you share your configuration? That "store" folder is not standard at all, I just checked a project that I host on firebase at the index.html is in the "dist" folder by default

Comment: Do you mean the firebase.json ? sorry im completely new to it. 'store' is the name of my project

Comment: angular.json and firebase.json should be enough to understand what's wrong, or simply host your repo somewhere (e.g. github) and share it here

Comment: I have uploaded the files in this link
https://github.com/indrajitravi/angularfirebase.git

Comment: Thanks for the effort, i did a change the angular.json file by editing the output path from "dist/store" to "dist" and it worked fine.